# Is boost::asio asyn_read with timer a good idea?

Tags: boost-asio

My server app needs to keep thousands of TCP connections. One time, I used one timer for each connection. Once a timer is expired, my code will check database to see if there is a message is ready for sending or not, if found then send it to remote client. This design works but the performance is very very slow, because there are thousands of timers in my app. My friend asked me to remove all timers and use one thread to check the database and send them to all remote clients in for(...) loop.

But I see a lot of articles that introcuce how to use dead_line_timer with async_read, see below link
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/stream_receive_timeout.cpp

My question is, does this work well when server has thousands of connections? I guess not, how do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the timers are not your main performance problem. They have of course some penalty, but by far not in the dimensions that the IO itself has.
I could imagine that your main problem is that you have a a large delay betweeen change-in-db -> timer-expired -> send happens. Another problem could be that you check your whole DB when a timer expires? If yes then you could only set a flag when an update happens, check for that in the timer and reset in when you sent the update.

Can you directly send the changes after they happen so that you avoid the timers at all? You could use `io_service->post()` to trigger an update function which sends the update to all connected clients. You should also use the `async_write` methods to avoid that a single client blocks your whole application.
If you don't want to send all updates but only in given intervals then your friends suggestion to use a single timer for checking for changes and sending the updates sounds also good.

Comment: I read the doc, but still do not know how to use io_service->post to update all connected clients. Could you give me an example?

Comment: `io_service::post` simply let's you queue a function call that should be executed during the next run of the event loop. Therefore it's similar to creating a deadline timer with a timeout of 0 and invoking the function on finish. An example would be io_service->post(std::bind(&YourClass::sendUpdates, yourObject, [parameters])) to defer the call of YourClass::sendUpdates

Comment: Thanks, I think io_service::post is a good way to notify all clients, your advice is useful. I will use it instead of a large mout of dead line timers.